# Why apache need authorization for url with username and password?

Tags: apache-2.4, http-basic-authentication

I build basic authorization in apache.Only one line in `/var/www/html/remote.html`.

```
<p>it is a test </p>
```

Now to verify the username and password with curl.

```
curl -u xxxx:xxxx -v  http://111.111.111.111/remote.html
*   Trying 111.111.111.111...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 111.111.111.111 (111.111.111.111) port 80 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'xxxx'
> GET /remote.html HTTP/1.1
> Host: 111.111.111.111
> Authorization: Basic dGVzdHBhc3M6MTIzNDU2Nzg=
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 07 Sep 2018 03:32:42 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization,DNT,User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type,accept,origin,X-Requested-With
< Last-Modified: Fri, 07 Sep 2018 03:22:41 GMT
< ETag: "b2-5753f8537e26c"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 178
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 

<p>it is a test </p>
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host 111.111.111.111 left intact
```

Input `http://111.111.111.111/remote.html?username=xxxx&password=xxxx` in browser,the authorization window pop up.

[image]

The url has contained right username and password verified by curl ,why remote.html can't be shown directly?
Why my url `http://111.111.111.111/remote.html?username=xxxx&password=xxxx` can't provide authorization info to apache server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL for basic authentication is

```
http://testpass:12345678@111.111.111.111/remote.html
```

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Basic Auth credentials are sent in a specific header from the client to the server - they are *not* appended to the URL in that way. You can verify this by noting that

```
curl http://111.111.111.111/remote.html?username=xxxx&password=xxxx
```

Also doesn't work - the `-u` flag knows to send it differently, and do does your browser *when you enter the creds into the form provided*.

Answer (score 0):

use following and also check [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399087/curl-to-access-a-page-that-requires-a-login-from-a-different-page) and [How to enter login CLI](https://superuser.com/questions/640839/how-to-enter-login-information-for-a-website-from-the-linux-command-line)

```
curl --user user:pass http://myweb.com/hello.html
```